# SessionsPerEra doesn't seem to be affecting sessions per era

Tags: session, chainspec, wasm, epoch, era

Am I fundamentally misunderstanding how staking handles election timings, please?  I've been trying to change the number of eras in a session, to increase the number of elections for testing.

I expected that we get a validator election every era, so reducing the sessions per era should increase the frequency of elections.  I found and modified this constant, which was originally 6:

`pub const SessionsPerEra: sp_staking::SessionIndex = 2;` in bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs

It's showing as changed in storage according to Polkadot.js, but I'm still getting 6 sessions per era anyway? (Chain started from genesis with this setting.)

[image: Image showing staking.sessionsPerEra = 2, staking.currentEra = 5 and session.currentIndex = 28]

I've also managed to create another example, where I have 6 sessionsPerEra defined in the code, but the chain is hanging after 2 sessions, with Babe complaining that there is an unexpected change of era. I've been trying 1, 2 or 6 sessions per era, trying to work out what's wrong.

Comment: Did you fixed it?

Comment: Yes - I'd built the chainspec when staking.sessionsPerEra was set to 6, and then changed the parameters in the code base and recompiled the substrate binary.  The mismatch was causing the error, I think.  (It was worse the other way - sessionsPerEra = 2 in the chainspec code block but 6 in the binary seems to cause the chain to hang.)  I'm not sure if this is github issue worthy - it might just be covered by the "don't change this on a live chain" comment already in the codebase?  Either way, I'll try to update / answer this and/or my other related bug with something helpful for future errors.

Comment: `sessionsPerEra` in the chain spec code block? What you mean by this?

Comment: Well, it might mean that I'm still not fully understanding things.  I assumed that constants like stacking.sessionsPerEra are included in the code blob in the `"genesis": { "runtime": {  "system": { "code: {}}}}` in the chainspec that gets encoded as `genesis --> runtime --> top` when you process the chainspec to raw. However, I guess that doesn't actually make sense - the whole point of them being constant is that they don't need don't need to be read from storage.

Comment: I'm sure that the problem was a mismatch between the code bloc in the chainspec and the values compiled into the binary though - when I replaced the code blob with an updated one, everything started to work reliably.  I'll have to dig into it a bit more - I have the broken files in version control still, I think.

Answer (score 2):

If you are updating your runtime, currently you compile it twice for native and for wasm. When both are exactly the same you should use the same `spec_version`. In your case here, you updated the native runtime, but did not bumped the `spec_version`. So, the node was thinking that both are compatible, but as this was wrong your chain was running into errors.

These kind of values like `SessionsPerEra` are also not easily changeable after your chain was launched. So, ensure that you rebuild everything and also have recreated your chain spec.

Comment: Thanks. I'm building test case chain specs, so they always restart from nothing, rather than building on an existing chain. The process I'm now following when I update something in the runtime is: 
recompile with `cargo build`; 
generate a new empty chain spec with `chain-spec-builder generate -c sampleChainSpec.json -a 1 -n 1 -e 1`; 
copy the "code" blob from the empty chainspec to my existing one; 
raw encode it again with `substrate build-spec --chain=chainspec_plain.json --raw > chainspec_raw.json`.  
Does that look sufficient?  Is there an easier/better way?